# Prevent last updated property from changing when updating node in code?

Tags: nodes, 9

I have this code that updates a node in a queue worker:

```
      $changed = $entity->getChangedTime();
      // Don't update the changed time by 
      $entity->setChangedTime($changed);
      $entity->set('my_field', "my_data");
      $entity->setNewRevision(FALSE);
      $entity->save();
```

Here is a screenshot of xdebug showing `changed` and `after_save` value with the relevant code:
[image]

But no matter what I do, the changed property keeps getting updated to the time of the update.

I tested the functionality in a different contenxt like:

```
  $node = Node::load($nid);
  $changed_time = new DrupalDateTime('2022-01-01 12:00:00');
  $timestamp = $changed_time->getTimestamp();
  $node->setChangedTime($timestamp);
  $node->save();
```

and this seem to work.

Why does my code in the queue worker fail to do the same thing? is it because it's updating a field value?

Comment: Did you verify you are actually getting value in `$changed = $entity->getChangedTime();` ?

Comment: @miststudent2011 yeah. I added a screenshot and of the values and relevant code. Maybe something else is acting on it when fields are being updated.

Comment: The changed time will always updted when saving a node. If you need a different timestamp, you will need to create another timestamp on the entity to track whatever it is you're trying to track.

Comment: @Jaypan do you know where is that happening? it feels like `$node->setChangedTime($timestamp);` should do it. but you may be right, if it's changed then it's always updating it.

Comment: I figured this out. The issue is that when I try to keep changed time to the original changed, Drupal overrides it. If I add a second, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/preserve_changed) that could help with your request. It's a bit hackish but it works.